# How to Remove Gmail Search History

Tags: gmail

I'd like to clear my Gmail search history. I saw this video, and thought it would help me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ReYtFia-uCU

But it doesn’t. The item in question I want to delete doesn’t have the clock icon nor an "X" next to it. It's got a magnifying glass. But deleting all my Google history from all time, and stopping Activity History, has not helped.

Answer (score 1):

**Please note: you can only delete the searches that you created yourself.

System suggested searches can not be removed**.

The magnifying glass to the left of the search term that you mention means that it is a system generated search therefore cannot be deleted.
Only the ones that you created will carry the little clock icon to the left followed by the `X` sign on the right.

Comment: Is that so eh? Can anyone tell me why the hell gmail would have...perverted system generated searches -that seem to be taken from the titles of emails I have received but deleted?

Comment: @Xenolith There is nothing we can do about it. At least you now know why this happens. If you could mark my answer as having addressed your question, I would appreciate the points -as per [site guidelines](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the search box. When you will click on the search text box then you will see the list of search keyword history.
2. When you will mouseover on a search item then you will see a cross (Delete) button on the right side. You have to click on this button to delete a search keyword. You can delete all search history one by one. If you also do not want to delete some item then you can leave them as it is. Those items will still show in your search history.

For more detail, please visit my website: https://www.techfactree.com/blog/how-to-delete-gmail-search-history/

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange! Please note that whenever you link to your own website, you must explicitly state so; read the [help center](/help/promotion) for more details.

Comment: Okay. I will remember it.

Answer (score 0):

For the 2019 version.Once a mail is received or sent the contact get saved in your gmail contacts. To ensure they don't come up again when searching;

1. Click on top right corner 9 dots
2. select contacts
3. Search for the name you want to delete and click on the name. Their contact card should appear
4. click the 3 dots found on the right of the card
5. select delete.

This will make sure it never appears again.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there is a way to do it from the web app, but you can do it from the mobile app for sure. To do this, go to *Settings* → your account → scroll to the bottom → *Clear search history*.